# how to insert an array on the node of the linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I have a problem while I'm trying to put an array of Strings on the Node of the LinkedList and this is the code which I have used.

```
public class Node { 

    public Node next ; 
    public String[] data;

    public Node (Node next ) {
        this.next = next ;
        this.data = new String[6];
    }
}
```

This is the add function to add the array inside the `Node` of the `LinkedList`:

```
public void add() {
    Node current = head;
    if (head == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            head.data[i] = numData[i];
        }
    } else
        while (current != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        current.data[i] = numData[i];
    }
}
```

> Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your add method, `current` is `null` in the last `for` loop and apparently if head be `null` you would have problems too. It seems you forgot to initiate new instances when you want to add a new node. change your method as below:

```
    public void add()
    {
       Node current = head ; 
       if(head == null ){
           head = new Node(null); //here you need to initiate head
           for(int i = 0 ; i<6 ; i++){
               head.data[i] = numData[i] ; 
           }
       }
       else {
           while(current.next != null){
           current = current.next ; 
           }
           Node newNode = new Node(null); //initiating a new node
           for(int i = 0 ; i<6 ; i++){
               newNode.data[i] = numData[i] ;
           }
           current.next = newNode;
       }
    }
```

I just assumed you want to put data in a new node. If you want to add data to the last existing node, just change the last part of the method.

Answer (score 0):

need to change logic

```
Node current = head ; 
       if(head == null ){
       for(int i = 0 ; i<6 ; i++){
       head.data[i] = numData[i] ;  //here you will get npe beacuse you are using null reference  of head
          }
       }
       else 
       while(current != null){
       current = current.next ; 
       }
       for(int i = 0 ; i<6 ; i++){
           current.data[i] = numData[i] ;//here you will get npe beacuse you are using null reference  of current
            }
       }
```